# “He didn’t drive the car into his garage even once”

Tags: difference

Should I change the sentence “He didn’t drive the car into his garage even once” into “He has not been able to get his own car into his garage even once”?

Comment: Both are fine - both grammatical and idiomatic. But notice the one with “able to” has a different meaning. It suggests not only didn’t he *choose* to use the garage, but he was not *able to* use it - something stopped him doing so (perhaps it was locked, or the access was too difficult for him).

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

These are two different sentences :

- **"He didn't drive the car into his garage even once"** states that he refused to do it. The car was never in the garage because he did not want to drive the car into the garage. It also does not say whether the car was his own.
- **"He has not been able to get his own car into the garage even once"** means that something prevented him from driving his own car into the garage. He couldn't do it rather than didn't want to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot...